# how to fire an event to a control button(switch) in android application that will save/record the state of the control switch

Tags: android, switch-statement

I done a small app with a control button(switch button)

I want to save the state of the control button whenever I exit the application it can  automatically reload the last state of the control that i use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my solution to my problem by using  `SharedPreferences`

just import `android.content.SharedPreferences`

in private class  I put this code

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
```

from the https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

the above code will allow class applications to store and retrieve user and system preference and configuration data.

You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

If you just want to retrieve data to any activity of your application you can use `Intent`

see this link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html